# How to structure controllers using swift?

Tags: swift, controller, ios8, navigationcontroller

I want to build an app using swift with the following structure:

1. Login/Signup screen
2. Home screen with slide out menu on the left
3. Different Pages in the menu -> same level like home screen

![Picture of the structure][1] 
// Sorry not enough reputation for posting images

Here is an example, but I don't understand it.
[GitHub-Link](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu) 
![Picture of the controller structure][2]

Why is the Login-Screen the rootViewController of the Navigation Controller?
Why is there no "back" button on the other controllers of the menu (Friends, Profile)?
I could remove the segue from Login to Profil and the app still works fine...it's a normal push segue. I don't understand what that sequel does.

I thought every controller which is not the rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller gets pushed on the stack and a "back" button...

Should i split the Login and the Signup screen into two different controllers?

My suggestion: 
1. Login screen/Signupscreen 
=> Modal segue to navigation controller 
2. Navigation Controller => RootViewController: Page 1 
But how should I implement the Page 2, Page 3,... at the same hierarchical level as Page 1

How would you structure the controllers?

[1]: http:// i.imgur.com/qHMy6zs.png 
 
[2]: http:// i.imgur.com/wdOGCGa.png

Looking forward to your answers! 
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the Login-Screen the rootViewController of the Navigation Controller?

It does not have to be, it's a design decision, personally I would not do it that way.

> Why is there now "back" button on the other controllers of the menu (Friends, Profile)?

Pushing a view controller onto a UINavigationController will do this automatically unless you specify that the back button should not be present in the view controller that gets pushed. UIViewControllers have a property called UINavigationItem where you can set the back button to hidden. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW6).

> I thought every controller which is not the rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller gets pushed on the stack and a "back" button...

Yes that's right, you sort of just answered one of your previous questions.

> Should i split the Login and the Signup screen into two different controllers?

Yes that would generally be a good idea. Have a separate view and view controller for each of them. It does depend on your ui design also.

> How would you structure the controllers?

It appears you have multiple menus and different sections to your app. In that case using a UITabBarController combined with multiple UINavigationControllers (one navigation controller per tab) may be one way to go about it, I've used this technique before and it works well.

If I a mistaken based on your images and you actually just have one main menu then stick to just one UINavigationController and just push and pop view controllers, have one view controller / view per view/page of your app.

Best thing is to read up about [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html) and [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) and decide what suits how you want to layout your views / your design.